# Graph generated by Voronoi diagrams

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Set of points generate Voronoi diagram on plain (black poins on image) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram#mediaviewer/File:Euclidean_Voronoi_Diagram.png if two points generate neighboring cells on Voronoi diagram, I would like to connect them with undirected edge, this way graph is generated. I would like to find this graph for 2D case.

I know there is **Fortune's algorithm**, but it generates Voronoi cells, not the graph, I suppose that my problem is easier, but I don't see solution not invloving genaration of Voronoi diagram first (edges separating cells seem to be needed for finding this graph).

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [Delaunay triangulations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation), there are a number of algorithms that can calculate it. My favourite is via the convex hull of $(x_i,y_i,x_i^2+y_i^2)$, you can find more info [here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/gbooks/new281-282.pdf) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/86420/48565).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: infortunately this isn't Delaunay triangulation, I think I should edit my question

Comment: @Qbik Why not? What you have described is exactly the [dual graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) of the Voronoi diagram.

Comment: @dtldarek is correct. Check the [relationship between the Voronoi diagram & Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation#Relationship_with_the_Voronoi_diagram).  If not, revise your question to explaining what needs to be different.